# Steam icon pixely. (I use budgie but I guess that doesn't mather.)

Tags: icons, 18.04, steam, budgie

My steam icon is very pixelated help.

[I want the icon to the right look like the icon Im holding my pointer on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9TJN.png)

Comment: Can you point out the problem on your image? The tray icon looks ok.

Comment: @OrganicMarble the steam icon down to the right is pixely see the picture in full screen and you will see.